# How does the stack choose which reason to cite for "on-hold?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When a question is put on hold, assuming a mod hasn't closed it, five members have voted to close the question for reasons.

How does the stack choose which reason to cite? Is it a majority based decision; do the reasons have an order of precedence?

So, two A's, a B, a C, and a D would cite A?

Is the decision influenced by the reputation of people voting?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185983/229547) but not really a definitive answer, even if you click around the related questions.

Comment: The rules are laid out in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100362/what-reason-would-appear-on-closed-question-with-2-2-1-votes) from 2011. They were also explained in the [old version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/10583/33) of the FAQ post on Meta.SE, but this paragraph has since been removed without an explanation.

Comment: @DrunkCynic The reason cited for voting to "close" a question could be adjusted to list each reason for each user, instead of displaying only a single reason; see [Proposal: Include form for user that votes to close as “unclear” to clarify what is “unclear” and when edits clarify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313344/234746); [Explain the reasoning behind voting to place this question “on hold”](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/701/14781). One option that does not exactly resolve the issue: select "off-topic" -> "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)" -> write your reason.

Comment: @guest271314 The citation is about changing what a vote is, not how the sum of votes to close are evaluates to select the quoted cause.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Where is a vote changed?

Answer (score 6):

ChrisF's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100363/295232) is still correct: the system will

- Take the reason a moderator used to close (if applicable).
- Take the reason with the most votes.
- In the event of a tie, take the reason of the last vote cast out of those involved in the tie.

So yes, it's a majority based decision; no reason has an innate precedence over the others; and the reputation of the people voting doesn't matter. In your example, reason A would be shown.

<sub>I have no idea why that was removed from the FAQ. Maybe it wasn't *frequently* asked anymore?</sub>